# Why wouldn't I use npm to install yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

In [the blog post announcing yarn (an alternative npm client)](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360) they say, "The easiest way to get started is to run `npm install -g yarn`". But if you go to [the "install yarn" page in their docs](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install), "npm install yarn" isn't listed on any of the platform-specific installation pages, and it's only offered as the third of three options on the "Alternatives" page. Furthermore when you `npm install` yarn it prints a deprecation warning, "It is recommended to install Yarn using the native installation method for your environment." So my question is if `npm install` is the easiest installation method, why isn't it a recommended method in their docs? Are there disadvantages to installing yarn using `npm`?

Comment: npm install is definitely listed: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#install-via-npm

Comment: @halfpastfour.am When I visit that link it redirects me to https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#mac-stable which does not list npm as an installation method

Comment: Akright, try this and scroll down https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-stable

Comment: @halfpastfour.am As stated in the question text, npm is indeed listed as the third of three options on the "alternatives" page.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

#### Edit (2020/11/23):

Thanks to @Kissaki for providing an update on Yarn's advice in the comments.

As of Yarn 2.x, the Yarn team has altered their advice and now suggests installing the tool via npm. This advice centers around the advantages of locking the version of Yarn used on a per-project basis. This allows projects to be resilient to variations between versions of Yarn.

From the new Yarn ["Installation" page](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install):

> Using a single package manager across your system has always been a
> problem. To be stable, installs need to be run with the same package
> manager version across environments, otherwise there's a risk we
> introduce accidental breaking changes between versions - after all,
> that's why the concept of lockfile was introduced in the first place!
> And with Yarn being in a sense your very first project dependency, it
> should make sense to "lock it" as well.
>
> For this reason, Yarn 2 and later are meant to be managed on a
> by-project basis.

This is similar to other methods of locking build tool versions on a per-project basis. See the [Gradle Wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) for an example.

The advantages of a standalone Yarn installation fall apart rather quickly, particularly with the Yarn team's change in direction. Installing via npm is now suggested, and instructions for standalone installations no longer appear to be offered on their site as of Yarn 2.x.

---

#### Original Answer:

According to the Yarn project maintainers, installing Yarn via npm [goes against the goals of the project](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1082#issuecomment-254026649), can cause issues, and is, in general, worse than platform-specific installation methods.

---

Advantages to recommended platform-specific installation:

- The Yarn teams regards npm as insecure and unreliable. From the "Install via npm" section on Yarn's ["Installation" page](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-stable):

> **Note:** Installation of Yarn via npm is generally not recommended. Installing Yarn with npm is non-deterministic, the package is not signed, and the only integrity check performed is a basic SHA1 hash, which is a security risk when installing system-wide apps.
>
> For these reasons, it is highly recommended that you install Yarn through the installation method best suited to your operating system.

- Running Yarn, which is a separate package manager utility, via npm can lead to edge-case issues (see [issue 2072](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2072))
- Installing via a system package manager decouples Yarn from npm, allowing you to run Yarn without npm
- The system package manager typically runs regularly, keeping Yarn updated
- Installing Yarn via npm is [slow](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2077#issuecomment-265280075)

Advantages to `npm install -g yarn`:

- Quick and easy (`npm install -g yarn`)
- Can be done in any npm environment (platform-agnostic)
- Familiar paradigm and process for Node.js developers
- Can be easily updated (`npm update -g yarn`)

  - A Yarn update command exists (`yarn self-update`) but it seems to be [broken](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1139)
- No dependence on system package managers
- Can use different versions of Yarn for different projects or different versions of Node.js via `nvm`

---

The system package manager arguments for the recommended installation tend to break down when referring to Windows, where there is no official package manager (unless you count Windows Update). Also, Windows package managers such as Chocolatey are often not configured for automatic updates.

I'm not sure that I fully agree with the Yarn team's decision on this, but they do make some fair points. The Yarn project is still young and if it is to become a replacement for npm then it wouldn't make sense to encourage npm as its primary installer.

Regardless, installations via npm seem to work just fine for now in most cases.

---

Sources:

- [npm vs system package manager explanation](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/275#issuecomment-248513143)
- [Additional explanation](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2077#issuecomment-265280075)
- [Short comment on the "app" vs "npm package" goal for Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1082#issuecomment-254026649)
- [Issue on how to keep Windows Yarn up to date](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1021)

Comment: Opinion: It seems like the real answer is because yarn is a competitor to npm. So they need a path for adoption that does not involve npm.  I personally agree yarn is better but I find it a bit silly to say installing yet another package manager (Homebrew), is a better option than using npm which is already installed, works cross-platform, and can be versioned between projects.

Comment: Another opinion: The easiest and more flexible way is via `curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash`. Their advice makes sense; why to *depend* on some other software, when willing to install a *dependency manager*? I think this is the main reason; the business competition is played fairly since they even suggest NPM as one of the methods. Just, since they wrote a software to compensate the mess that NPM and its development processes have become in the last years, it's pretty obvious that they underline all the flaws of it, and dissuade against using it as starting point for Yarn.

Comment: Another opinion: If yarn is really better (I agree), it doesn't really matter whether you use npm to install or not. We all know that the last time you opened IE was to download Chrome.

Comment: I think that the cache problem issue which happened when installing yarn with npm can also happen when installing it in another way, so I find it biased to present things like that.

Comment: In my recent experience, npm install of yarn doesn't reliably give you an executable that is usable.

Comment: Today I experienced my first case where it was _better_ to install yarn via npm: Netlify. Since I first followed the official recommendation and installed via the msi, yarn was missing from `package.json`, causing the Netlify deploy job to throw a "yarn: command not found" error. After doing an `npm install yarn` and pushing out the updated `package.json` containing `"yarn": "^1.22.10"`, sure enough Netlify deployments finished without a hitch.

Comment: This seems to no longer be the case. 3 years later (to this answer), the installable version 1 is hosted [only on the 'classic' subdomain](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable) of the yarn website. [The main Installation page](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install) speaks of versions 1 and 2, and 2 being the successor to 1. It also only speaks of npm install for installation. So it seems like now and going forward the npm tool is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the update @Kissaki! I've updated the answer to reflect the Yarn team's latest recommendation.

Comment: even after installing yarn like above steps, getting error yarn command not found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66637032/bash-yarn-command-not-found-even-after-installing-it-globally, please check and clarify

Answer (score 24):

There's no visible disadvantage to installing Yarn through `npm`. In fact I chose this method myself because of a few reasons:

1. It's clearly the easiest way to do it. `npm i --global yarn` and you
   can literally replace `npm` with `yarn` on your console immediately.
2. If you're using `nvm` and maintaining different code projects on each NodeJS version, then you can install Yarn on one version and not have it on the other
3. Honestly, the only reason I can think of that it is not mentioned in the Platform Specific installs, is that npm is platform agnostic

Answer (score 7):

Because `npm` is not platform specific and runs on almost any system it is listed as an Alternative. There is no advantage or disadvantage over the platform specific installs. The difference would be the install location but all methods expose the global `yarn` command to your CLI.

I would argue they listed it as "the easiest way" because most people are already very familiar with `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use npm to install yarn because: as of May 2022, installing on ubuntu according to the official documentation of nvm and Yarn via npm breaks capistrano scripts.

```
bash: yarn: command not found
```

Yarn works in the ssh terminal session.

Detailed Description "Why does something work in my SSH session, but not in Capistrano?" https://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

So I removed the default install of nvm nodejs yarn,

```
$ npm uninstall -g yarn
$ nvm deactivate
$ nvm uninstall 16.15.0
$ nvm unload
$ rm -r ~/.nvm
```

and installed yarn like this:

```
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
$ curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
$ echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
$ node -v
v16.15.0
$ npm -v
8.5.5
$ yarn -v
1.22.19
```

Capistrano scripts are now working.