# nvm-windows and Installing global packages with Yarn - How do I use Yarn correctly?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, nvm-windows

I made the switch to [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). I installed all of my global packages using npm for each version of Node that I have installed. I can verify all of these packages are installed in:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\[node version]`

I also installed Yarn globally for each version of Node:

```
nvm use latest
npm install -g yarn
nvm use lts
npm install -g yarn
nvm use 16.20.0
npm install -g yarn

Etc...
```

What I don't quite understand is why all yarn globally installed packages get dropped in the `yarn global bin` folder:

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin`

How do global yarn packages work with different versions of Node (I.E. If I switch from latest to lts)?

For example, I installed [nodemon](https://yarnpkg.com/package/nodemon) via `yarn global add nodemon`. But when I type `nodemon` into the command-line, it's not recognized.

I can add `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin` to my `PATH` environment variable, but this doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't global Yarn installs be tied to the version of Node that's currently selected by nvm-windows?

I think I have the same issue as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108816/can-yarn-and-nvm-coexist-on-windows). All yarn global packages are installed in the same directory no matter what version of Node that's selected with `nvm-windows`. To steal a direct quote from another post:

> Yarn insists on some kind of global install location (separate from what nvm controlled node versions see).

In short: How am I supposed to use Yarn with `nvm-windows`? Should I just stick to `npm`?